# Display images and not allow hot linking

Tags: image, coldfusion

We need to display ~40 images in a page and not allow users to hot link those images. We are currently using `<img src="...">` which points to a handler that checks the `cgi.http_referer` and display the images using `cfcontent`. However, some images will fail to load (~6 images out of 40), if I refresh the page, some other images will fail to load.

This problem seems to appear when I have to display more than 10 images. I suppose this is because I'm using `cfcontent`? If so, what should I use instead?

Comment: Just reminded me of http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2170-Streaming-Secure-Files-Efficiently-With-ColdFusion-And-MOD-XSendFile.htm

Comment: I'm with Henry on this one, this is much better solved at the web server level than the ColdFusion level. But even then, if people want those images, they're going to get them. More Ben Nadel to the rescue :) http://www.bennadel.com/blog/314-ColdFusion-CGI-Variables-Hot-Linking-And-Poor-Documentation.htm

Answer (score 3):

To find out exactly why those images are failing, you'll need to do a little more work. You should use something like Firebug in FireFox, or the console in Safari or Chrome, to find out what's happening with those requests that are failing. You can also use something like [Fiddler on Windows for IE](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Charles on the Mac, Windows, or Linux](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to see the full HTTP requests that are happening in the background, along with the full return values from your ColdFusion app server. Until you know exactly why they're failing, we can't come up with any sort of solution.

The other thing to remember, is that if you do this via ColdFusion, then for every page load, you're hitting your CF server with 40 more requests. So one page then results in 41 hits to your CF server for processing. Make sure that code is as tight as it can possibly be.

If I was going to go this route, I'd do it at the server level (IIS or Apache) using some sort of server-level filter to prevent the hotlinking. But just remember, that there will always be a way around it.

Comment: In Chrome's developer tool, it alerts me of my disappearing images being "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html." Even if I hard-coded my cfcontent's type as image/jpeg it's still telling me they are text/html

Comment: That tells me that an error may be occurring during those requests. My suggestion would be to install Charles, run your file, and then scroll through the session results in Charles and look at the raw response from the server for those requests that failed. I'm guessing there is a CF error on those pages, which is why your return would be `text/html` instead of `image/jpeg`.

Comment: I can't install Charles somehow, but I did install Fiddler and the disappearing images have an error msg of "Element VIEWPATH is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression." that seems to be coming from Coldbox. Anyway I tried bypassing Coldbox and call a cfm with the `cfcontent` and it seems to be working.

Comment: the viewpath error is from Coldbox: [http://groups.google.com/group/coldbox/msg/555a472457926ed1](http://groups.google.com/group/coldbox/msg/555a472457926ed1)

Comment: That could be if your ColdBox instance is running in development mode and it's reiniting on every request. If you're slamming the Coldbox installation, you could be ending with with scope contention issues. Another reason to let this type of thing happen at the sever level instead of the application level.

Comment: I don't enough about ColdBox to be able to tell you where to go from here, but at least now you know where the CF issue is and can begin tracking it down...

Comment: FYI I resolved this issue by moving `cfcontent` that display the image to a coldbox proxy cfc. Seems like this is a bug from Coldbox event handler.